# Deactivating my account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have my own reasons to deactivate the account. I need to deactivate it for now and reactivate it later. How can I do it? I already tried writing "please delete me" in my about me and also filled up the form for which I was supposed to receive mail but the account is not deleted. Why?

Comment: Because deletions require a human and at christmas time perhaps people are on holiday for a while?

Comment: "deactivate it for now and reactivate it later" - there's no way to do this though; a deletion is final

Comment: ok so how can i delete it.....i followed the steps but it is not working.....

Comment: Just give it a bit of time. As Martijn said, deletion requires human oversight. It is currently Christmastime in the western world and, additionally, a weekend, so requests are likely to take some time

Comment: ok....thank you for the response

Comment: Do you have any hats you have to get rid of first?

Comment: If its irreversible then I will keep this account.....@Chris Geken....Sorry, i did not understand your question!!

Answer (score 17):

**Deleting your account is not the same as deactivating it.**

Deletions are basically irreversible. We cannot restore your account for you if you decided to delete it but then changed your mind.

We currently don't have a way to do what you want at all. If you don't want to use your account right now, but think you'll need it again in the future, your best bet is to just walk away and let it sit for a while.

That being said... I don't see any emails from you. I'll have to check to make sure our help form is working properly. But in the meantime, let me know in comments here what you'd like to do - delete your account or keep it.